# How to call C-File via Prolog?

Tags: c, swi-prolog

I want to access predicates written in a C-File into a prolog file using:

> :- use_foreign_library(foreign(mylib)).

But it doesn't work. I just want to implement the example [here](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=foreignlink) from swi-prolog itself, but I get the following error:

> c:/users/julian/desktop/prologc/mylib.pl:2:
> c:/users/julian/desktop/prologc/mylib.pl:2: Initialization goal raised exception:
> '$open_shared_object'/3:

[image]

The file structure looks like:

[image]

What am I missing? Shouldn't this work with copy and paste?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/issues/392

Comment: Post text as text, not _pictures of text_.  Apart from anything else it makes copying pasting into a translator possible: _"Das angegebene modul wurde nicht gefunden" == "The specified module was not found"_.  Which says it all really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Das angegebene modul wurde nicht gefunden"
> Translation: "The specified module was not found"

The Prolog program has not found mylib.dll.  Did you create it?

You cannot *call* a C *file* (or even a function in a C file).  C is not an interpreted language, the C source must be compiled then packaged into a DLL (dynamic link library).  The module you need to load is mylib.dll which you create using a C compiler.

How you do that will depend on what toolchain you choose to use.  In Visual C++, the easiest in is to start with the DLL template project - though do ensure C rather then C++ compilation by naming the source file with the .c extension.  In MinGW/GCC the steps would be something like:

```
gcc -c -o mylib.o mylib.c
gcc -o mylib.dll -s -shared mylib.o -Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Clifford, this was the solution. The followup problem is, that I get know errors with the defined predicates:

mylib.o:mylib.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `PL_get_atom_chars'

I embedded the swi-prolog.h via  #include "C:/Programme/swipl/include/SWI-Prolog.h" in the c-file.

Comment: @Johnny "undefined reference" is a linker error.  Including the header only provides declarations to allow compilation, you also need to link swipl.lib. Maybe https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/LibAndInclude.html helps.